# Enumerations vs int flags?

Tags: java, int, enumeration

Just wanted some opinions on the matter. I have always used int flags, and was just curious on possible performance of ease of use if I were to use enumerations in Java?

Comment: What language are you talking about?   For example, in C# they are one and the same.

Answer (score 12, accepted):

I very much doubt you'd see *performance* benefits - and in some cases there may even be performance penalties, depending on how you're using them. I doubt they'd be significant though.

The benefit isn't in terms of performance - it's in terms or expressing your intentions more clearly, leading to more readable (and type-safe) code. For example, with integer flags nothing's going to complain if you try to use (say) HTTP_STATUS_UNAUTHORIZED as a value for your file sharing mode in a method call... whereas if both of those were enums, the parameter would be strongly typed to *really* only allow file sharing modes (or null, admittedly, assuming you *are* talking about Java).

Answer (score 7):

As usual, [Effective Java](http://java.sun.com/docs/books/effective/) says it best:

> Programs that use the `int` enum
>   pattern are brittle. Because `int`
>   enums are compile-time constants, they
>   are compiled into the clients that use
>   them. If the `int` associated with an
>   enum constant is changed, its clients
>   must be recompiled. If they aren’t,
>   they will still run, but their
>   behavior will be undefined.
>
> There is
>   no easy way to translate `int` enum
>   constants into printable strings. If
>   you print such a constant or display
>   it from a debugger, all you see is a
>   number, which isn’t very helpful.
>   There is no reliable way to iterate
>   over all the `int` enum constants in a
>   group, or even to obtain the size of
>   an `int` enum group.

(+ 10 more pages of why enums are better :-))

**Source:** [Item 30: Use enums instead of `int` constants](http://my.safaribooksonline.com/book/programming/java/9780137150021/enums-and-annotations/ch06lev1sec1)

Comment: Thank you for this, it is highly descriptive.

Answer (score 5):

Enumerations more clearly express what you are trying to do.  Use them and do not worry about performance; performance impact will be negligible.

Answer (score 2):

An equivalent of using bit mask flags is to use EnumSet (which happens to use a bit mask)

```
enum Colour { RED, GREEN, BLUE }
Set<Colour> colours = EnumSet.noneOf(Colour.class);
colours.add(Colour.RED);
colours.add(Colour.GREEN);
if (colours.contains(Colour.RED)) // true
   System.out.println(colours+" contains RED");

if (colours.contains(Colour.BLUE)) // false
```

Answer (score 0):

They're basically the same thing except enumerations are self-documented.  I recommend using enumerations as soon as someone else might be in contact with your code.

Comment: Java enumerations are very much not the same thing as integers. They are much more powerful than that (and than the enums in most other languages).

Comment: You're right, they're more powerful and are type-safe.  What I probably did not express adequately is that plainly replacing int flags by enums will yield the same results except in a more readable manner.

Answer (score 0):

An [Enum](http://doc.java.sun.com/DocWeb/api/java.lang.Enum) a type with its own methods and [optimized containers](http://download.oracle.com/javase/6/docs/api/java/util/EnumSet.html).  You should prefer it over int flags because it's safer and possibly more efficient (though I doubt there's very much in it at all!).

Answer (score 0):

In addition to the type-safe code, you have a single-reference to share the collection (re-usability)